# RemoveFromSuperview(): different behavior in iOS SDK5?

Tags: c#, objective-c, cocoa-touch, events, xamarin.ios

I'm experiencing crashes when running my app on iOS5.
The code constellation I have:

- UIViewController **A** has an event "`InputEnded`".
- UIViewController **B** adds **A**'s view as a subview and attaches to `InputEnded`.
- In `InputEnded`, **B** removes **A**'s view from super view, removed the event handlers, disposes **A** and sets it to NULL.

In iOS 4.3 this works as expected, however A's `ViewDidDisappear()` is never called, but that's okay.

In iOS 5 however, A's `ViewDidDisappear()` ***DOES*** trigger. It gets fired some point later in time. But the issue is: it **fires even though A is already disposed** (Handle == 0) and hence it will crash!

I both, A and B I override bool `AutomaticallyForwardAppearanceAndRotationMethodsToChildViewControllers` and return FALSE to keep the same behavior as I see in iOS 4.3 but appearently it will always call its own `ViewDidDisappear()`, no matter what you return.

Can somebody explain what is going on here and how to overcome it?

Comment: Hard to say without source code. I'll have a look at it if you can make a small, slef-contained, test case and attach it to a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com

Comment: I doubt it is a MT bug but I will create a sample.

Comment: I doubt too - the bindings are pretty direct in this case. OTOH we won't know unless we investigate :) and maybe we can do something to avoid the crash (where Handle is 0)

Comment: Here you go: http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2161
 Keep me posted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why a crash occurs is that the **A** should not have been *manually* disposed, only null'ed.

Disposing **A** destroyed the native representation of the controller and, for iOS5 SDK, it was still required when a call to `ViewDidDisappear` was made later. The crash did not occur with iOS4.3 SDK because it did not call `ViewDidDisappear`.

So simply null'ing **A** means the user code has no more reference to the (managed) instance and let the GC collect it later (once nothing else has a reference to it). This works under both SDK versions and the memory is reclaimed in both case (confirmed by adding a finalizer to **A** to output a string to MonoDevelop's *Application Output* once executed).

Full test case and explanation are available on [bugzilla](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2161).